# How I can calculate this number

Tags: real-analysis, math-software

How I can calculate exactly this number:

$$
\frac{(\sqrt{3}+2)^{2^{333111366}}+1}{(2^{333111367}-1)(\sqrt{3}+2)^{2^{333111365}}}
$$

Several softwares do not support this number.

Comment: Some of what you typed looked ambiguous: for example, did you intend the numerator to be  $(\sqrt{3}+2)^\left({2^{333111367-1}}\right)+1$ or $(\sqrt{3}+2)^\left({2^{333111367}-1}\right)+1$ or something else?

Comment: You have calculated the number exactly. What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: @Henry: It is the first case.

Comment: @DavidH: I want to see its value. For example is that number an integer.

Comment: @DER I've got answer for that, but What are you gonna do with that number?

Comment: @DER It is clearly not an integer, for it is lower than 1 and greater than 0 (strictly).

Comment: @Martigan: How you can do that

Comment: @DER So you want a decimal approximation? Approximations are by there very nature inexact...

Comment: @DigitalBrain: It is a factor in a differential equation.

Comment: @DavidH: Yes, I want decimal approximation.

Comment: @DER Sorry... I misread (it was written so little and without my glasses...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{(2+\sqrt3)^{2^{333111366}}+1}{(2^{333111367}-1)(2+\sqrt{3})^{2^{333111365}}}$$If this is Your Number,
The [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%282%2Bsqrt%283%29%29%5E%282%5E%28333111366%29%29%2B1%29%2F%28%282%5E%28333111367%29-1%29*%282%2Bsqrt%283%29%29%5E%282%5E%28333111365%29%29%29) says
It's

$$10^{10^{10^{8.001199221375904}}}$$

and it also [says](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is%20x%3D10%5E%2810%5E%2810%5E%288.001199221375904%29%29%29%20a%20natural%20number%3F) that It's **not** a positive integer

Comment: @ Digital Brain: So this is a natural number.

Comment: @DER his post says the opposite. It says that it is NOT an integer.

Answer (score 1):

The number is so large it cannot be reasonably represented.  I ignored the $+1, -1$ and took the log in [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%28%28%28%28sqrt%283%29%2B2%29%5E2%5E%28x-1%29%29%2B1%29%29%2F%5B%282%5Ex-1%29%28%28sqrt%283%29%2B2%29%5E2%5E%28x-2%29%29%5Dfrom%200%20to%2010). The result is  a little over $10^{10^8}$, so in decimal would have more than that many digits.  Note that $3+\sqrt 2 \gt 2$ and dividing the two terms involving it leaves (ignoring the $+1$ in the numerator) $3^{2^{333111365}}$ which *completely swamps* the puny power of $2$ in the denominator, which only has about $10^8$ digits